# File system not working after installing CTParental on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, filesystem, filemanager

After installing CTParental on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, file system hangs; no longer works.  Is there a fix for this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I installed a different file manager and it resolved the problem.  I installed one called, "files from the Snap Store (Ubuntu Store).